# Félix's or Félix'?

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives, apostrophe

Very important question! My friend Félix and I have a group called "Asteflix Novices". We have no idea if the correct way of spelling it would be "Asteflix' Novices" or "Asteflix's Novices".

I heard at school that words ending in S and X would take only an ' while the rest get an 's, but Félix doesn't believe it's correct. Who is right? What is the correct rule?

Comment: How do you pronounce it when it possesses and when it does not possess ?

Comment: And what does Félix have to do with this?

Comment: I know of no words in English that end with an *x* followed by a bare apostrophe. If you were to use the French spelling and talked about *those plateaux’ oddities* you might just might get away with it, but people would look at you funny.

Comment: Have you looked at the duplicate? What matters is what you actually say. Speech is primary and the spelling follows directly from that, without tricks, surprises, or exceptions. The apostrophe is SILENT. It is not a letter and so never represents a sound. Do you say Felics things or Felicses things? I'll bet anything it's #2.

Comment: @tchrist Because I am not natively English, I have no idea how to pronounce Felix's correctly in English, so the "write like you pronounce" thing doesn't help me at all! You could have written an answer, too, that would've been nice